# How can I compare a value received from selenium web-driver to another value without hard-coding the other value?

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, automation

I am currently having trouble finding the best way to compare values from a webpage collected by Selenium Web-Driver to another source of values.

Methods I have tried:

- Comparing the Web-Driver values to excel spreadsheet cells but this is too slow and would cause cell numbers to be changed when a new row is inserted
- Hard-Coding the values into the selenium tests, this method works but means that if the value on the webpage changes the value in the test has to be manually changed throughout

I have thought about the possibility of using a database and then requesting the values from a table but have not tried this yet.

Comment: Assert.assertEquals("Value", "Expected_value");

Comment: I understand that this is how you compare 2 values I am looking for a way to compare 2 values without hard-coding the "Expected_value" into the test. So it can be changed without having to manually change each "Expected_value" within the test.

Comment: Please share your code what you tried...

Comment: Are you trying to compare what is displayed on one screen with what is displayed on another? or are you trying to compare what is in the database compared with what is on the screen? Either way, just query first screen/database, store the value that you are expecting, query the page under test, and compare values.

Comment: I dont think that you're going to find a good way around this, whether you use a website, spreadsheet, or database at some point you'll have to do an update somehow. What's concerning is that if  you're expected value is constantly changing how can you ever conduct any testing?